# How to cancel an XslTransform.Transform in progress

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

So once you start a long-running XslTransform.Transform, how do you abort it?

```
    XslTransform XslTransform = new XslTransform();

    XmlDocument stylesheetDocument = new XmlDocument();
    //TODO: Handle error when styhlesheet doe snot exist
    stylesheetDocument.LoadXml(stylesheetXml);
    XslTransform.Load(stylesheetDocument.CreateNavigator());

    FileStream FileStream = new FileStream(outputDocument.Path, FileMode.Create);
    try
    {
        XslTransform.Transform(inputXmlDocument, XsltArgumentList, FileStream); // raises XSLTException
    }
    catch (XsltException xsltException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(xsltException.Message);
    }
    catch (XPathException xPathException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(xPathException.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }

    FileStream.Close();
```

Comment: I believe you would have to do the transform in another thread and then kill it if you need to cancel it.

Comment: @TyCobb, if you answer I'll mark it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Transform` call is not asynchronous.

You'll need to do the transformation in another thread. Your main thread will then have to kill the transformation worker when it needs to be cancelled.